# Wire_frame in matplotlib 1.5 doesn't plot correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I am trying to plot a wireframe using `plot_wireframe` from the `Axes3D` module. My dataset: three 2D arrays: two created with `np.arange` and then `np.meshgrid`. The third one is an array containing results of function "f2" (f2 = f(x, y)). I expected 3D plot, but result is 2D plot in 3D space. Now I made some code that looks like a part of documantation of mpl, but still doesn't work. Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

def f2(x, y):
    '''Return f(x, y) = exp(-(x * x + y * y)) * sin(-5. * (x * x + y * y))'''    
    return np.exp(-(x**2 + y**2)) * np.sin(-5.0 * (x**2 + y**2))


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x2 = np.arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.02)
y2 = np.arange(1.5, -1.5, -0.02)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x2, y2)

z2 = f2(X, Y)

ax.plot_wireframe(X, X, z2, rstride=10, cstride=10, linewidth=0.1,
                     label='$\exp(-(x^2 + y^2)){sin}(-5.0(x^2 + y^2)$')

plt.show()
```

That is what I want:
[Beautiful 3D plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOruP.png)
But the reality is cruel:
["A plot I've got"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VOvM.png)

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Is it a problem with values of vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ax.plot_wireframe(X, X, z2, rstride=10, cstride=10, linewidth=0.1,
                 label='$\exp(-(x^2 + y^2)){sin}(-5.0(x^2 + y^2)$')
```

to

```
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, z2, rstride=10, cstride=10, linewidth=0.1,
                 label='$\exp(-(x^2 + y^2)){sin}(-5.0(x^2 + y^2)$')
```

You are using `X` instead of `Y` as the second argument to `ax.plot_wireframe`. Thus, all points fall on top of the diagonal `Y=X`.